# BigQuery- No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: BOOL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table where I am doing a CTE aggregation. Code:

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(ad_id=-1) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time DESC) grp
FROM data
```

This works fine in MySQL but in BigQuery, the part "SUM(ad_id=-1)" gives me the error:

```
No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: BOOL. 
Supported signatures: SUM(INT64); SUM(FLOAT64); SUM(NUMERIC)
```

Is there any turn around for this kind of problem?

This is how my data looks:

[image]

And my aim is to get a new column 'grp' which counts the number of ad_id = -1 coming in each user id.
So output wanted is something like this:

[image]

Workspace (MYSQL): https://dbfiddle.uk/MoRzpg0y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple addition of 'case when' can work:

```
SELECT *, 
sum(case when ad_id = -1 then 1 else 0 end ) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time DESC) grp
FROM data
```

Comment: With BQ you don't have sumif but countif exists.
So: countif(ad_id = -1) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time DESC) grp should work